# Serial to USB cable from a scale to PC ,some values are just question marks

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, usbserial

Im traying to write a program to read data from a old AND scale using a serial to USB converter cable to display in a textbox .i was able to write a program successfully to read data only from a RS232 serial cable, but when I  attached a serial to USB cable to it, it only displayed some numbers and others are just question marks.  (Ex: ???0.3?2?)

method i used to read data .

```
 private void PortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        while (_port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // PostKeys
            var original = _port.ReadExisting();
         
            // Reformat string to fit SendKeys()
            var reformattedString = DefaultFormatter.Reformat(original);
            try
            {
                SendKeys.SendWait(reformattedString);
            }
            // Handle exception caused if keys are sent to an application
            // not handling keys
            catch(Exception ex)    
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Is that a problem that I can over come through a code or is that the serial to USB cable is malfunctioning ?

Comment: Parity?  Baud rate?  Stop bits?

Comment: The scale might use proper RS-232, i.e. signals with -12V and +12V while the USB to serial adapter likely only used 0V and 5V.

Comment: @Codo will 5volt to 12 volt converter usb  may be solve it ?

Comment: @MartinJames i have tried with different baud rates and parity. didnt know stop bits has to do anything with it . do i have to compare with the scale settings ?

Comment: First measure the voltages on the serial port of the scale to ensure it really uses +/-12V. Then either buy a USB-to-RS232 converter supporting 12V, or if you're sufficiently familiar with electronics build a level converter yourself.

Comment: What is the model number of the scale? Looks like there are drivers for USB for some models: https://www.aandd.jp/products/software/software.html - look beneath "Driver Software" . Main website: https://www.aandd.jp/

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus your original output with the question marks "?" look a lot like mismatching Parity setting and a standard "parity error" behavior where bytes with mismatching Parity are replace by a '?' ASCII 63 character. Note that the working answer from user9938 defines "Port.Parity = Parity.Even. Port.DataBits = 7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code below with a USB serial port device, which may also work with your scale. Some of the port settings were found by downloading/installing [WinCT (RsCom, RsKey & RsWeight)](https://www.aandd.jp/products/software/software.html)). Then, in the Windows Start menu under **A&D WinCT**, select either `RsCom` or `RsKey`. Using `RsCom` or `RsKey` is an easy way to check that your USB cable/connection is working. I used both "RsKey" and "RsCom" with my USB serial device, and it seemed to work.

**Create a WinForms project**

**VS 2017**:

- Open Visual Studio
- Expand **Installed**
- Expand **Visual C#**
- Click **Windows Desktop**
- Select **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Specify project name (name: ReadSerialPort)
- Click **OK**

**VS 2019**:

- Open Visual Studio
- Click **Continue without code**
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- **C# Windows Desktop**
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Click **Next**
- Specify project name (name: ReadSerialPort)
- Click **Create**

**Note:** From this point forward, the process is the same for both VS 2017 and VS 2019.

**Add class**: SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs

**Note:** This class will be used with an event that sends the data received from the serial port device to a subscriber.

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs.cs)

**SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public delegate void SerialPortDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs e);

    public class SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
    {
        public string Data { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

        public SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs(string data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Reference to System.Management**

- In VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Reference**
- Expand **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Management**
- Click **OK**

**Add class**: ComPorts

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: ComPorts.cs)

**ComPorts.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public class ComPorts
    {
        public List<ComPortInfo> Ports { get; set; } = new List<ComPortInfo>();
    }

    public class ComPortInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PortName { get; set; }

        public ComPortInfo()
        {

        }

        public ComPortInfo(string name, string portName)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.PortName = portName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add class**: HelperSerialPort

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: HelperSerialPort.cs)

**HelperSerialPort.cs**

```
//if using .NET 5, install NuGet Package: System.IO.Ports

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public enum PortBaudRate : int
    {
        Baud1200 = 1200,
        Baud2400 = 2400,
        Baud4800 = 4800,
        Baud9600 = 9600,
        Baud14400 = 14400,
        Baud19200 = 19200,
        Baud28800 = 28800,
        Baud38400 = 38400
    };

    public class HelperSerialPort : IDisposable
    {
        public delegate void SerialPortErrorReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e);

        public event SerialPortDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;
        public event SerialPortErrorReceivedEventHandler ErrorReceived;

        private string _dataReceived = string.Empty;
        public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort Port { get; private set; }

        public HelperSerialPort()
        {
            //create new instance
            Port = new SerialPort();
        }

        public string Connect(string comPort, PortBaudRate baudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600)
        {
            string portName = string.Empty;
            string result = string.Empty;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(comPort))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("COM port not selected.", "Error - COM Port", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return "Error: COM port not selected.";
            }

            try
            {
                if (Port == null)
                {
                    //create new instance
                    Port = new SerialPort();
                }

                if (!Port.IsOpen)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("opening port");

                    //create new instance
                    Port = new SerialPort(comPort);

                    //set properties
                    Port.BaudRate = (int)baudRate;
                    Port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                    Port.Parity = Parity.Even; //Even,None,Odd supported
                    Port.DataBits = 7;
                    Port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                    Port.ReadTimeout = 200;
                    Port.WriteTimeout = 50;
                    Port.DtrEnable = true; //enable Data Terminal Ready
                    Port.RtsEnable = true; //enable Request to send

                    //open port
                    Port.Open();

                    //subscribe to events 
                    Port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
                    Port.ErrorReceived += Port_ErrorReceived;

                    //set value
                    result = "Connected";
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("else");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Error: (Connect) - " + ex.Message;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("result: " + result);
            
            return result;
        }


        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose();
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Port != null)
            {
                if (Port.IsOpen)
                {
                    Port.Close();
                }

                //unsubscribe from events
                Port.DataReceived -= Port_DataReceived;
                Port.ErrorReceived -= Port_ErrorReceived;

                Port.Dispose();

                Port = null;
            }
        }

       
        public ComPorts GetComPortInfo()
        {
            ComPorts comPorts = new ComPorts();

            SortedDictionary<string, string> comPortNameDict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
            SortedDictionary<string, string> portDict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

            string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            //get USB COM ports
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_PnPEntity"))
            {
                ManagementObjectCollection pnpEntityItems = searcher.Get();

                if (portNames != null && pnpEntityItems != null)
                {
                    var props = pnpEntityItems.GetEnumerator();

                    foreach (ManagementBaseObject mbo in pnpEntityItems)
                    {
                        if (mbo != null)
                        {
                            object nameObj = mbo.GetPropertyValue("Name");
                            object pnpClassObj = mbo.GetPropertyValue("PNPClass");

                            if (nameObj != null && pnpClassObj != null)
                            {
                                if (pnpClassObj.ToString() == "Ports" && nameObj.ToString().ToLower().Contains("(com"))
                                {
                                    string name = mbo.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString().Trim();
                                    //Debug.WriteLine("name: " + name);

                                    string portName = string.Empty;

                                    if (name.Contains("(") && name.Contains(")"))
                                    {
                                        portName = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("(") + 1, name.IndexOf(")") - name.IndexOf("(") - 1);
                                        //Debug.WriteLine("Port Name: '" + portName + "'");
                                    }

                                    if (!portDict.ContainsKey(name))
                                    {
                                        //add to dictionary - ex: Voyager 1450g, COM1
                                        portDict.Add(name, portName);

                                        //add to dictionary - ex: COM1, Voyager 1450g
                                        comPortNameDict.Add(portName, name);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //add any ports that aren't USB -- ie: RS-232 (serial) devices
            //USB devices are already in the dictionary, so only add devices 
            //that don't already exist in the dictionary
            if (portNames != null && portDict != null && comPortNameDict != null)
            {
                foreach (string name in portNames)
                {
                    if (!comPortNameDict.ContainsKey(name))
                    {
                        //add to dictionary
                        portDict.Add(name, name);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in portDict)
            {
                //add to list
                comPorts.Ports.Add(new ComPortInfo(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
            }

            return comPorts;
        }

        private void Port_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: (sp_ErrorReceived) - " + e.EventType);

            if (this.ErrorReceived != null)
            {
                ErrorReceived(this, e);
            }
        }

        private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            _dataReceived = Port.ReadExisting();

            Debug.WriteLine("_dataReceived: " + _dataReceived);

            if (this.DataReceived != null)
            {
                SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs eventArgs = new SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs(_dataReceived);
                DataReceived(this, eventArgs);
            }
        }

        public void SerialCmdSend(string data)
        {
            if (Port.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Send the binary data out the port
                    byte[] hexstring = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    //write to SerialPort
                    foreach (byte hexval in hexstring)
                    {
                        byte[] _hexval = new byte[] { hexval }; // need to convert byte to byte[] to write
                        Port.Write(_hexval, 0, 1);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: Failed to SEND" + data + "\n" + ex.Message + "\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Port is not open. Please open the connection and try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: You may need to install a USB driver. [AND Driver Software](https://www.aandd.jp/products/software/software.html).

Create an extension method that can be used with RichTextBox.

**Create class** (ControlExtensions)

See [How to update a RichTextBox from BackgroundWorker using BeginInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983137/how-to-update-a-richtextbox-from-backgroundworker-using-begininvoke)

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: ControlExtensions.cs)

**ControlExtensions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired) control.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(action), null);
            else action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Next we'll add some controls and code to Form1.

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer, double-click **Form1.cs** to open the designer.

**Add "Connect" button to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **Button**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form
- In Properties Window, for "button1", set **(name)**: btnConnect; set **Text**: Connect
- In Properties Window, click [image] (Events). Double-click **Click** to add event handler to Form1.cs

**Add "Disconnect" button to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **Button**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form
- In Properties Window, for "button1", set **(name)**: btnDisconnect; set **Text**: Disconnect
- In Properties Window, click [image] (Events). Double-click **Click** to add event handler to Form1.cs

**Add RichTextBox to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **RichTextBox**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form
- In Properties Window, for "richTextBox1", set **(name)**: richTextBoxReceivedData

**Add "Load" event handler to Form1**

- In Properties Window, for "Form1"", click [image] (Events). Double-click **Load** to add event handler to Form1.cs

**Add "FormClosing" event handler to Form1**

- In Properties Window, for "Form1"", click [image] (Events). Double-click **FormClosing** to add event handler to Form1.cs

**Modify Form1.cs code**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.cs**
- Select **View Code**

**Option 1** (doesn't automatically detect when a USB device is plugged in/unplugged):

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HelperSerialPort helperSerialPort = new HelperSerialPort();
        private ComPorts comPorts = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get COM port info
            GetComPorts();
        }

        private void HelperSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Data: " + e.Data);

            richTextBoxReceivedData.Invoke(() =>
            {
                richTextBoxReceivedData.AppendText(e.Data);
                richTextBoxReceivedData.Refresh();
            });
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (helperSerialPort.Port == null || !helperSerialPort.Port.IsOpen)
            {
                helperSerialPort.Connect("COM3", PortBaudRate.Baud9600);

                helperSerialPort.DataReceived += HelperSerialPort_DataReceived;
            }

        }
        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            helperSerialPort.Dispose();
        }

        private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (helperSerialPort != null && helperSerialPort.Port != null)
            {
                helperSerialPort.Dispose();
                helperSerialPort = null;
            }
        }

        private void GetComPorts()
        {
            //get COM port info
            comPorts = helperSerialPort.GetComPortInfo();

            foreach (ComPortInfo cpInfo in comPorts.Ports)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Name: '" + cpInfo.Name + "' PortName: '" + cpInfo.PortName + "'");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2** (automatically detect when a USB device is plugged in/unplugged):

**Note**: Some of the code below is from: [Check for device change (add/remove) events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events)

**Create class** (UsbDeviceNotification)

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: UsbDeviceNotification.cs)

**UsbDeviceNotification.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public static class UsbDeviceNotification
    {
        public const int DbtDevicearrival = 0x8000; // system detected a new device        
        public const int DbtDeviceremovecomplete = 0x8004; // device is gone      
        public const int WmDevicechange = 0x0219; // device change event      
        private const int DbtDevtypDeviceinterface = 5;
        private static readonly Guid GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice = new Guid("A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED"); // USB devices
        private static IntPtr notificationHandle;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr recipient, IntPtr notificationFilter, int flags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr handle);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct DevBroadcastDeviceinterface
        {
            internal int Size;
            internal int DeviceType;
            internal int Reserved;
            internal Guid ClassGuid;
            internal short Name;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers a window to receive notifications when USB devices are plugged or unplugged.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="windowHandle">Handle to the window receiving notifications.</param>
        public static void RegisterUsbDeviceNotification(IntPtr windowHandle)
        {
            DevBroadcastDeviceinterface dbi = new DevBroadcastDeviceinterface
            {
                DeviceType = DbtDevtypDeviceinterface,
                Reserved = 0,
                ClassGuid = GuidDevinterfaceUSBDevice,
                Name = 0
            };

            dbi.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(dbi);
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(dbi.Size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(dbi, buffer, true);

            notificationHandle = RegisterDeviceNotification(windowHandle, buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Unregisters the window for USB device notifications
        /// </summary>
        public static void UnregisterUsbDeviceNotification()
        {
            UnregisterDeviceNotification(notificationHandle);
        }

    }
}
```

Then use the following code in Form1.cs:

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ReadSerialPort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private HelperSerialPort helperSerialPort = new HelperSerialPort();
        private ComPorts comPorts = null; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get COM port info
            GetComPorts();
        }

        private void HelperSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Data: " + e.Data);

            richTextBoxReceivedData.Invoke(() =>
            {
                richTextBoxReceivedData.AppendText(e.Data);
                richTextBoxReceivedData.Refresh();
            });
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (helperSerialPort.Port == null || !helperSerialPort.Port.IsOpen)
            {
                helperSerialPort.Connect("COM3", PortBaudRate.Baud9600);

                helperSerialPort.DataReceived += HelperSerialPort_DataReceived;
            }

        }
        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            helperSerialPort.Dispose();
        }

        private void FrmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (helperSerialPort != null && helperSerialPort.Port != null)
            {
                helperSerialPort.Dispose();
                helperSerialPort = null;
            }
        }

        private void GetComPorts()
        {
            //use SynchronizationContext.Current with ThreadPool to avoid the following error:
            //Transition into COM context...for this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: 
            //An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call. 
            //Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_INPUTSYNCCALL)

            var sc = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                //do work on threadpool
                sc.Post(delegate
                {
                    //get COM port info
                    comPorts = helperSerialPort.GetComPortInfo();

                    foreach (ComPortInfo cpInfo in comPorts.Ports)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Name: '" + cpInfo.Name + "' PortName: '" + cpInfo.PortName + "'");
                    }
                }, null);
            });

        }

        private void UsbDeviceAdded()
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code

            Debug.WriteLine("Info: USB device added");


            //get COM port info
            GetComPorts();
        }

        private void UsbDeviceRemoved()
        {
            //ToDo: add desired code

            Debug.WriteLine("Info: USB device removed");

            //get COM port info
            GetComPorts();

        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == UsbDeviceNotification.WmDevicechange)
            {
                switch ((int)m.WParam)
                {
                    case UsbDeviceNotification.DbtDeviceremovecomplete:
                        UsbDeviceRemoved();
                        break;
                    case UsbDeviceNotification.DbtDevicearrival:
                        UsbDeviceAdded();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

Here's some additional info that may be useful:

**Open PowerShell and run the following**:

- `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_SerialPort Where Name like '%COM%'"`
- `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_SerialPortConfiguration"`
- `Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Cimv2 -Query "Select * From Win32_PnPEntity where PnPClass = 'Ports' and Name like '%COM%'"`
- `mode`