# Why cannot I receive information through COM port?

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm writing two applications, which are supposed to communicate to each other. One is written in C++ for Arduino (Teensy, more specifically), second is a desktop app written in C#.

Usually the communication works correctly. However, sometimes I have trouble receiving information from Teensy. In those situations the log says:

```
00:00:00.00    | Serial port service      | Trying to open port COM4...
00:00:00.00    | Serial port service      | Closing port COM4...
00:00:00.00    | Serial port service      | Opening port COM4...
00:00:00.00    | Serial port service      | Opened port COM4...
00:00:00.00    | Serial port service      | Bytes to read: 0
```

The code behind this log looks like following (`serialPort` is a `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`):

```cs
public void OpenPort(string port)
{
    logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Trying to open port {port}...");

    ClosePort();

    serialPort.PortName = port;

    try
    {
        logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Opening port {port}...");
        serialPort.Open();
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
            logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Opened port {port}...");
        else
            logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Open call exited, but port is not opened");

        opened = true;
        this.port = port;

        configurationService.Configuration.LastUsedPort = port;
        configurationService.Save();
        logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Bytes to read: {serialPort.BytesToRead}");

        DataReceived?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    catch
    {
        logService.AddLog(SerialPortLogSource, $"Failed to open port {port}...");

        opened = false;
        this.port = null;
    }
}
```

When I afterwards initiate communication from the device, I get nothing. However, what's interesting, if I only open the serial port monitor in Arduino IDE, I receive some information, which I was supposed to get in my application and moreover from this point on, communication with my application starts working. This is a scenario, which is reproducible every single time.

The whole project is available [on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/spook/MacroKeyboard), more specifically, this is `MacroKeyboard.Satellite`.

What may cause such weird behavior? What may happen in Arduino IDE's serial port monitor, what unclogs the serial port?

Comment: From a debug perspective have you tried opening a port outside of this method and just checking the input buffer at a regular interval?

Comment: I think that the problem may lie elsewhere. From the behavior of the device it seems like that if I don't open the Serial Monitor from Arduino, device doesn't pass `while (!Serial) ;` part. It looks like some magic must happen for the virtual USB Serial port to initialize properly. However, I have no idea, where to search for answers in this regard.

Comment: I would suggest posting the sketch as well. This may be more of an electronics stack exchange question. I have done similar to what you have shown here, and have not seen the same behavior.

Comment: Note that "COM" is sometimes used for "Component Object Model". So I would consider changing the title to something like "Serial COM port" to avoid possible ambiguities. You might also want to read some [criticism of system.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70441938/get-scale-weight-over-serial-from-mettler-toledo-rice-lake-scale/70614758#70614758 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666331/serialport-doesnt-actually-open-the-virtualcom-port/66666984#66666984