# Serial Port communication using C# SerialPort.readLine() not working properly

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-forms-designer

I am building a Windows Form Application in visual studio. This is my form1.cs file,

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.IO.Ports;       // used to access the SerialPort Class

    namespace Simple_Serial_VS2013
    {
       public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        string logTxt;
        string Port_Name;
        string ReceivedData;
        delegate void serialCalback(string val);
        string Selected_Port_Baudrate; //used for storing selected Baudrate and COMport,for displaying purposes 
        int Baud_Rate;
        static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

        //Populate the Combobox with SerialPorts on the System
        ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());

        //Disable both Transmit and receive functions 
        GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = false;
        GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled  = false;

        // Disable Baudrate Selection also
        ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates.Enabled = false; 

        // Displaying System Information 

        string SystemInformation;//Used for Storing System Information 

        SystemInformation  = " Machine Name = " + System.Environment.MachineName;                                         // Get the Machine Name 
        SystemInformation  = SystemInformation + Environment.NewLine + " OS Version = " + System.Environment.OSVersion;    // Get the OS version
        SystemInformation  = SystemInformation + Environment.NewLine + " Processor Cores = " + Environment.ProcessorCount; // Get the Number of Processors on the System

        TextBox_System_Log.Text = SystemInformation; //Display into the Log Text Box
        
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // Will run, when user selects a serialport using Drop Down Menu
    private void ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Selected_Port_Baudrate = ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString() + " Selected"; // Store the Selected COM port

        TextBox_System_Log.Text = Selected_Port_Baudrate;  // Display the Selected COM port in the Log Text Box                                  

        ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates.Enabled = true;       // Enable Baudrate Selection after COM port is Selected

    }

    // Will run, when user selects a baudrate using Drop Down Menu after Serialport is selected
    private void ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Selected_Port_Baudrate = Selected_Port_Baudrate + Environment.NewLine;             
        Selected_Port_Baudrate = Selected_Port_Baudrate + ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates.SelectedItem.ToString() + " bps selected";
        TextBox_System_Log.Text = Selected_Port_Baudrate;  // Display the Selected Baudrate in the Log Text Box 

        //Enable both Transmit and Receive Groupboxes
        GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true;
        GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled  = true;
        Port_Name = ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();    // Store the selected COM port name to "Port_Name" varaiable
        Baud_Rate = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates.SelectedItem); // Convert the string "9600" to int32 9600
        SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate);
        COMport.Open();
        COMport.Write("*");
        COMport.Close();
    }

    private void TextBox_Data_Transmitted_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Not used
    }

    private void TextBox_Data_Transmitted_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Not used
    }

    //Used for sending data to SerialPort
    private void Button_Transmit_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Stop();


        GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled = false; // Disable the Receive Groupbox

        //Local Variables
                    
        string Data      = TextBox_Data_Transmitted.Text;                             //Store the string in Textbox to variable "Data"


        // MessageBox.Show(Port_Name);           // Debugging Purpose
        // MessageBox.Show(Baud_Rate.ToString());

        SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate); //Create a new  SerialPort Object (defaullt setting -> 8N1)
        COMport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataRecievedHandler);
        //try to Open SerialPort


        try
        {
            COMport.Open();
        }
        #region  
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException SerialException) //exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
            COMport.Close();
        }

        catch (System.IO.IOException SerialException)     // An attempt to set the state of the underlying port failed
        {
            MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
            COMport.Close();
        }

        catch (InvalidOperationException SerialException) // The specified port on the current instance of the SerialPort is already open
        {
               MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
               TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
               TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
               COMport.Close();
        }

        catch //Any other ERROR
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR in Opening Serial PORT -- UnKnown ERROR");
            COMport.Close();
        }
        #endregion

        //If we are able to open the port 
        if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Port Opened");
            COMport.WriteLine(Data);                // Send Data
            COMport.Close();                        // Close the Port
            GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled = true; // Enable the Receive Groupbox

            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + Data + "  Written to Port";
        }
        else
        {
            GroupBox_Serial_Receive.Enabled = true; // Enable the Receive Groupbox
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Write to COM port ");
            COMport.Close();
        }
    }

    //Used for Receiving Data from Serial Port
    private void Button_Receive_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTimer.Start();


        //GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = false; // Disable the Transmit Groupbox
        #region
        //Local Variables
        string Port_Name = ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts.SelectedItem.ToString();      // PortName
        int Baud_Rate = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox_Standard_Baudrates.SelectedItem);   // BaudRate
        ReceivedData = ""; //                                                    // String Containing Received Data
       

        SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort(Port_Name, Baud_Rate);
        #endregion
        COMport.ReadTimeout = 1500; //Setting ReadTimeout =3500 ms or 3.5 seconds

        //Open the Serial Port 
        #region
        try
        {
            COMport.Open();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException SerialException) //exception that is thrown when the operating system denies access 
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
            COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port
        }

        catch (System.IO.IOException SerialException)     // An attempt to set the state of the underlying port failed
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
            COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port
        }

        catch (InvalidOperationException SerialException) // The specified port on the current instance of the SerialPort is already open
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(SerialException.ToString());
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialException.ToString();
            COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port
        }


        catch //Any other ERROR
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR in Opening Serial PORT -- UnKnown ERROR");
            COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port
        }
        #endregion

        try
        {
            //If we are able to open the port 
            if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Port Opened");
                TextBox_System_Log.Text = Port_Name + Environment.NewLine + Baud_Rate;

                ReceivedData = COMport.ReadLine();                // Wait for data reception
                #region

                //if(ReceivedData.Split(' ').Length -1 != 2)
                //{
                //    ReceivedData = null;
                //}
                //else if(ReceivedData.Split('<').Length - 1 != 1)
                //{
                //    ReceivedData = null;
                //}
                //else if(ReceivedData.Split('>').Length -1 != 1)
                //{
                //    ReceivedData = null;
                //}

                setLog(ReceivedData);

                //TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Waiting for Data";
                //TextBox_received_Data.Text = ReceivedData;

                COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port

                TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + ReceivedData + "  Received from Port";
                #endregion
                GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true; // Enable the Transmit Groupbox
            }
            else
            {
                GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true; // Enable the Transmit Groupbox
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to Write to COM port ");
                GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true; // Enable the Transmit Groupbox
                COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port
            }
        }

        // Only catch timeout exceptions.
        catch (TimeoutException SerialTimeOutException)
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
            #region
            // Show in a Message Box 
            MessageBox.Show(COMport.ReadTimeout.ToString() + " milliSeconds Passed" + Environment.NewLine + "Operation Timed Out");
            MessageBox.Show(SerialTimeOutException.ToString());

            //Show in Log TextBox
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = COMport.ReadTimeout.ToString() + " milliSeconds Passed" + Environment.NewLine + "Operation Timed Out";
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + SerialTimeOutException.ToString();
            #endregion
            COMport.Close();                                  // Close the Port

            GroupBox_Serial_Transmit.Enabled = true; // Enable the Transmit Groupbox
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_Available_SerialPorts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void TimerEventProcessor(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button_Receive_Data.PerformClick();
    }

    private void DataRecievedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        sp.WriteTimeout = 1000;
        sp.ReadTimeout = 2000;

        sp.NewLine = "\n";
        //sp.WriteLine("@" + sendtemp + "#");
        string indata = "";
        while(sp.ReadChar() != '\n')
        {
            indata += sp.ReadChar();
        }
        //string indata = sp.ReadExisting(), logTxt;
        logTxt = indata;
    }

    private void setLog(string val)
    {
        if (this.TextBox_System_Log.InvokeRequired)
        {
            serialCalback scb = new serialCalback(setLog);
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox_System_Log.Text = TextBox_System_Log.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Waiting for Data";
            TextBox_received_Data.Text = ReceivedData;
        }
    }

    } //end of Partial Class Form1
}//end of namespace Simple_Serial_VS2013
```

The control flow is:

1. The user is asked to select the COM Port, then the baud rate
2. The user enters a number in the form of !213# (starting with "!" and ending with "#")
3. This number is taken in by the arduino which runs on the code -

   [This is a ss of the code (was having trouble formatting it over here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwDq2.png)
4. The arduino prints "111 222 T(settemp)" every one second to the serial port
5. This is read by the visual studio application and printed to two textboxes.

PROBLEM:
Some parts of the output text dont appear to show up, see attached image.
[111 appears as 11, this shouldn't be happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNOse.png)

TRIED SOLUTIONS:

1. Tried setting up a delegate for setting the textbox values, because I feel a single thread is doing all the serial communication as well in-program stuff.

FYI:
If I am using any incorrect programming terminology, I apologize for unintentionally confusing you. I am more of a hobbyist. Any help with this issue is highly appreciated. Thank You!!!

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66666984/10024425 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614758/10024425 , and [Serial Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Why are you closing the port at end of transmit?  The receive and transmit uses the same connection and you should not close until the application terminates.