# C# to and from Arduino DUE Serial Semaphore Time out

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, timeout, semaphore

it's my first question here in Stackoverflow so excuse me if I forget to mention something!

I am creating an interface for an industrial washing machine using a WPF C# app and an Arduino DUE.
They comunicate through a Serial Port.

Serial Port current settings:

- BaudRate = 115200
- Over USB cable (arduino programming port)
- DTR and Rts enabled
- WriteTimeout = 1000;

The Arduino is printing to the Serial Port without any delays, the states of all Analog input pins and a couple Digital input pins.

In the current state of the interface I try to simply turn on and off certain pins, however the c# app freezes and then crashes with the following error message = **"System.IO.IOException: 'The semaphore timeout period has expired."**.

Heres some experiences I've made and the following results:

- Reducing the BaudRate to 9600 managed to make it so some messages get through and the pins turn off and on, if I change them too fast the same error message occurs.
- With the baud rate back to 115200 and on the Arduino code i stop the sending of input pin states to the serial port, the error is gone and i can change pin states fast without any problems, but I won't be able to read anything from the arduino.

The Following code represents the arduino code with the sending of analog and digital input states enable.
To disable I comment the 2 last lines

```
void read_input_analog()
{
  for(int i = 54; i<= NUMBER_ANALOG_INPUT_PORTS; i++)
  {
    String pinNumber = "A";
    pinNumber += i;
    String message = "#A";
    message += i-54;
    message +=":";
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: 54 represents analog pin A0 and 64 Analog pin A11
    message += analogRead(i);
    message +='!';
    Serial.println(message);
  }
}

void read_input_digital()
{
  for(int i = 22; i<= NUMBER_DIGITAL_INPUTS; i++)
  {
    String pinNumber = "D";
    pinNumber += i;
    String message = "#D";
    message += i;
    message +=":";
    // IMPORTANT NOTE: 54 represents analog pin A0 and 64 Analog pin A11
    message += digitalRead(i);
    message +='!';
    Serial.println(message);
  }
}

void loop(){

  
  while(Serial.available()>=8)
  {
    char c = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(c);
    if(c == '#')
    {
      recieve_order();
    }
  }
  
  read_input_analog();
  read_input_digital();
}
```

**EDIT 1** Every property not mentioned in the Serial Port settings have been left at default.

> DataBits property defaults to 8, the Parity property defaults to the None enumeration value, the StopBits property defaults to 1

**EDIT 2**

I have noticed UART only works as Half Duplex which I mistakenly thought was Full Duplex. I have since added a delay to the sending of information from the arduino side with the use of the millis() function. This helped the problem quite a bit however the problem still persists but not as often.

**EDIT 3**

I have made it so the read code on the Arduino clears the buffer faster by appending a string everytime a byte enters the buffer instead of having it wait to fill 8 bytes before doing something.

It helped as sending individual messages no longer crashed the program, however now with a Slider to control an analog signal, the program crashes as scrolling through the slider sends a chunk of messages!

I have also tested with a Windows Forms project (That I Found online) and it's slider worked like a charm! No crash!

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80070079
  Message=The semaphore timeout period has expired.

  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int32 timeout)
   at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(String text)
   at Washing_Machine_Interface.Communication.Arduino.ArduinoProtocol.AnalogValue(Int32 pinNumber, Int32 power) in D:\André O Viking\Projetos\Washing_Machine_Interface\washing-machine-interface\WM_Interface\Washing_Machine_Interface\Washing_Machine_Interface\Communication\Arduino\ArduinoProtocol.cs:line 67
   at Washing_Machine_Interface.MainWindow.Pin2Slider_ValueChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1 e) in D:\André O Viking\Projetos\Washing_Machine_Interface\washing-machine-interface\WM_Interface\Washing_Machine_Interface\Washing_Machine_Interface\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 115
   at System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs`1.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.OnValueChanged(Double oldValue, Double newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Slider.OnValueChanged(Double oldValue, Double newValue)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Slider.UpdateValue(Double value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Slider.OnThumbDragDelta(DragDeltaEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Slider.OnThumbDragDelta(Object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseMoveThunk(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Washing_Machine_Interface.App.Main()
```

Comment: *"Over USB cable"* -- Please clarify: a UART interface or USB interface using CDC ACM.  If later, then why & how are *"DTR and Rts enabled"*?

Comment: @sawdust using UART interface, I have enabled dtr and Rts as an attempt to fix the problem acording to some information I came across but nothing changed and honestly I am not sure I understand the purpose! I enabled it while opening the serial port on the C# side

Comment: According to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue this board has 2 USB ports, which USB port are you using to communicate with C#? Have you installed the driver as described in the documentation? See https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Arduino_Genuino/getting-started-with-the-arduino-desktop-ide-623be4

Comment: @user9938 As mentioned in the original question I use the programming port of the Arduino DUE, yes I have it installed!

Comment: Your post shows very few serial port property settings. You may consider adding all of them to your post. The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777489/what-is-the-proper-use-of-serialport-basestream-beginread/68807066#68807066

Comment: @user9938 I have only specified those who have been changed, everything else is default. As I am new to serial communication I am not sure about what every thing does! DataBits property defaults to 8, the Parity property defaults to the None enumeration value, the StopBits property defaults to 1.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957066/serial-to-usb-cable-from-a-scale-to-pc-some-values-are-just-question-marks/65971845#65971845

Comment: @user9938 Unfortunately still no success, but I have edited the post with additional experiments I have conducted

Comment: "Does windows forms and wpf make a difference when interacting with Serial Ports?" -No.

Comment: You may want to see if changing the SerialPort `Handshake` property (and other associated properties) has any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I have figured out what happened!

## The Arduino Due was crashing do to an overflow of data coming from C#!

When it crashed C# would throw the Semaphore Timeout Exception and would never recover from it even when a try and catch was in place, and I gave it time to clear the traffic of all the data sent!

**Initially the message sent from C# was the following:**

`serialPort.Write("#30" + pinNumber + power + "\n");`

- '#' -> order
- 3 -> Analog Output
- '0'+pinNumber -> pin number (0 is added when the pin number has only 1 digit ex. 02 por pin 2)
- power -> value from 0-255
- '\n' -> end command

When using a slider it would send this message with a different power value many times and in a short time. **Crashing the Arduino** and requiring a reset.

**After days of testing I tried the following message as an experiment:**

`serialPort.Write(power + "\n");`

I temporarily changed the arduino code to only change pin 2, that way only a value to change to was required.

After this change , no matter how fast I dragged the slider from on side to the other, **the Arduino would comply and the problem was solved**.