# getting correct data from mettler teledo

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am reading data from a scale Mettler toledo using USB to RS232
I am successfully getting data with the following setting using C#.NET

```
Port.BaudRate = (int)baudRate;
Port.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;Port.Parity = Parity.Even; //Even,None,Odd supported
Port.DataBits = 7;

Port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
Port.ReadTimeout = 2000;
Port.WriteTimeout = 500;
Port.ReadBufferSize = 2048;
Port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
Port.WriteBufferSize = 1024;
Port.DtrEnable = true; //enable Data Terminal Ready
Port.RtsEnable = false; //enable Request to send
```

the setting on my display toledo is set to continuous output

I am able to get the weight in real-time, but it comes with a bunch of data as follows

**A*0     15     00**

or

**A*0     15     0**

or

[image]

The first set may vary but the middle one which is the weight changes according to what is on the scale

I did try to remove special characters using regex, reducing the white spaces and splitting the data, to get only the middle one but it wasn't successful

What I want to achieve is only to get the weight [middle value]

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70614758/10024425

Comment: Those are most likely control characters.

Comment: The following may be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946343/10024425, [SerialPort.DataReceived Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks), [SerialDataReceivedEventArgs.EventType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventargs.eventtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), [SerialData Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0),

Comment: I will try that and let u know

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: A*0 15 00

or

A*0 15 0

same result

Comment: Please add the model number of the scale and/or a reference to the documentation for the scale.

Comment: mettler teledo IND331

Comment: Please add the model number information to the original post.

Comment: [IND331 User's Guide](https://www.mt.com/dam/product_organizations/industry/Load_Cells/Downloads/Transmitter/ind131-331/manuals/IND131-331_MAN_64067481_08_EN_UG.pdf), p. 112 (C-1) states _no handshaking_ for both COM1 and COM2. Unless you've changed the values in the scale setup screen, the defaults are `Handshake.None`, `Parity.None`, `DataBits= 8`, `BaudRate = 9600`.

Comment: p. 114 (C-3) shows the format of the message under heading C.3.1. It starts with `STX` which is `0x02` (hex: 02) and ends with a carriage return. Therefore, you may need to set the [SerialPort.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) property to `NewLine= "\r"`. Then in `DataReceived` event handler: `if (e.EventType != SerialData.Chars) { return; } SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;  string data = sp.ReadLine(); System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data: " + data);`. Also see [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Elsewhere in the documentation, it's mentioned that `CRLF` (`\r\n`) is used, so you may also try setting `NewLine= "\r\n"` as `A` in the ASCII table is LF (line feed). `*` in the ASCII table is `0x2A` (hex: 2A) which is `00101010` in binary. One can use the Calculator app in Windows. Switch the calculator to "Programmer" mode, click "HEX", and enter `2A`. The binary value will be displayed. Then refer to page C-3 to see what each bit represents.

Comment: You may also consider reviewing `Little Endian` and `Big Endian` byte ordering.

Comment: Thank you very much, my code is working fine now

Comment: What did you do to fix the code?

Comment: I did an unconventional trick
based on your advice, I removed the ASCII data at the beginning of the line,

I was left with the weight and the 00 at the end
I created a list where I added all decimals only

if (Decimal.TryParse(aux[i].Trim(), out p))
                        list_poids.Add(p);


then from the list I grouped them based on the most recurring one, it seemed to work fine list_poids.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).Select(grp => grp.Key).First();

for now it seems to work, but not sure on the long run

Comment: An _unconventional trick_ shouldn't be necessary. Here are some other posts of mine that contain some pieces of code that one may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68807066/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946343/10024425. The following may be useful for getting a bit from a byte which according to the documentation one needs to do in order to determine what the data represents: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71388371/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72651487/10024425.