# Barcode Scanner c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Please educate me on barcode scanners. Is it true that when you scan a barcode, the barcode scanner will automatically pass data to your program, so if there is a textbox, when you scan it, the barcode will be parsed into that textbox without any code or certain references? This is all new to me. I'm currently developing a POS system in C#.

Comment: many / most modern barcode scanner devices will present themselves as a keyboard to the computer.

Comment: This is a question about hardware so might be more suited to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Read the documentation for the scanner(s) that you're interested in using. You may consider using a scanner that can be configured as a `USB Serial` device. This will allow you to use [SerialPort Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) which will allow your program to receive data without a particular control needing focus. If using a Honeywell barcode scanner, the following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74022784/10024425.

Comment: If using a `USB Serial` device, the following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on which barcode scanner you use, 99% of all scanners can be configured to act as a keyboard and then you can write input directly into a text field without any code if that is in focus.

Comment: This is typically called 'keyboard wedge' in the documentation.