# C# code not working for read serial port device

Tags: c#, serial-port, com-port

C# code not working for read serial port device. But hyptertemila, putty can get data from that device. Exception is "$exception

{"A device attached to the system is not functioning.\r\n"} System.IO.IOException"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS1qN.png)

my code is

serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

```
        serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPort_DataReceived;

        Console.WriteLine($"Reading from {portName}. Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        serialPort.Close();

    }

    private static void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This event will be called when data is received on the serial port
        // Read the data from the buffer and process it as needed
        string data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine($"Received data: {data}");
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the COM door is correct?

Comment: I recommend reading _all_ of the documentation for [Serial Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). The settings that you use in C# need to match the settings configured for the hardware device. You may also consider, checking with the manufacturer to see if a driver is available for your device. If so, install it. There are some PowerShell commands at the end of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425) that may be helpful.