# Why can't I send data to a USB device?

Tags: c#, .net, libusb, usbserial

I'm having trouble sending data to a connected USB device.

I am trying to write a program to automate data collection in some experiments. My measurement equipment is moved around by a Thorlabs PT3/M-Z8 three-axis motorised stage. Each of the axes is controlled separately by a KDC101 "K-cube" DC servo motor controller (three K-cubes in total for our setup). The K-cubes are all plugged into a KCH301 USB hub so that there's just one USB cable to my laptop. I'm working on an M3 MacBook Pro running MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 but I would like to make my program platform-independent so that anyone in our lab can use it (we have an approx. 50/50 split between Mac and Windows). The KCH301 USB hub and three KDC101 controllers are  detected by the "System Information" app, so I know they definitely work!

I am using C# targeting .NET 8. I'm using LibUsbDotNet 2.2.29 (installed from NuGet) to keep everything platform-independent. At some point I also had to install Mono and add LibUsb-1.0.0.dylib and LibUsb-1.0.dylib to the project/bin/debug/net8.0 file (still not 100% certain what they do).

I am aware that Thorlabs have a Kinesis DLL that can be used, but it only works on .NET framework 4.8.1 which doesn't help my platform-independent goal. Instead, Thorlabs recommend I use their APT protocol to send byte commands directly to the KDC101. The electrical interface within each KDC101 uses a FT232BM USB peripheral chip (made by FTDI) to communicate with the host PC. This is a USB2.0 compliant USB1.1 device which "provides a serial port interface to the embedded system (i.e., Thorlabs controller) and USB interface to the host control PC".

From the APT protocol:

> FTDI supply device drivers and interfacing libraries (for Windows, Linux, and other platforms) used to access the USB chip. Before any PC USB communication can be established with an Thorlabs controller, the client program is required to set up the necessary FTDI chip serial port settings used to communicate to the Thorlabs controller embedded system.

I have installed FTDI's D2XX [1.4.24](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/D2XX1.4.24.zip) driver for MacOS (which incidentally also seems to use LibUsb!) as well as the [D2xxHelper](https://www.ftdichip.com/old2020/Drivers/D2XX/MacOSX/D2xxHelper_v2.0.0.pkg). I have followed the install instructions detailed in their README document and the helpful [video install guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir2PVz1870E). About half-way through the video he says that once the D2XX drivers are installed "you may link to them in your build using -lftd2xx". This is where I get stuck. How do I "link" to a driver? For reference, I'm using the JetBrains Rider IDE.

I tried sending some basic commands to the KDC101 anyway, just to see if it would work. I used the following test code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;

namespace USB_Communication;

public class UsbPeripheralChipFT232BM
{
    //Put your Product Id Here
    private const int ProductId = 0xfaf0;

    //Put your Vendor Id Here
    private const int VendorId = 0x0403;

    public static void Main()
    {
        FindDevice();
    }

private static void FindDevice()
    {
        // Find your USB device by its vendor ID and product ID
        UsbDeviceFinder finder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x0403, 0xfaf0);

        // Initialize the USB context
        using (UsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(finder))
        {
            if (wholeUsbDevice == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device not found!");
                return;
            }

            // Open the USB device
            if (!wholeUsbDevice.Open())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not open USB device!");
                return;
            }
            
            //Open up the endpoints
            var writeEndpoint = wholeUsbDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep01);
            var readEnpoint = wholeUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);
            
            var dataToSend = new byte[64];
            dataToSend[0] = 43;
            dataToSend[1] = 04;
            dataToSend[2] = 01;
            dataToSend[3] = 00;
            dataToSend[4] = 22;
            dataToSend[5] = 01;
            
            writeEndpoint.Write(dataToSend, 5000, out var numBytesWritten);

            Console.WriteLine("Number of bytes written: " + numBytesWritten);
        }
    }
}
```

The command "43, 04, 01, 00, 22, 01" is an example taken directly from the APT protocol. It should cause the KDC101 to begin a homing sequence. Unfortunately, my KDC101 doesn't do anything and I get the response in the console "Number of bytes written: 0". I've tried changing the endpoint number but that doesn't seem to help.

So, after all that context, my question is: **Why can't I send this message through to the USB device?**

**Update**

I have had partial success by updating to LibUsbDotNet 3.0.102 from NuGet:

```
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.LibUsb;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;

namespace USB_Communication;

public class UsbPeripheralChipFT232BM
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var context = new UsbContext())
        {
            context.SetDebugLevel(LogLevel.Info);

            //Get a list of all connected devices
            using var usbDeviceCollection = context.List();

            //Narrow down the device by vendor and pid
            var selectedDevice = usbDeviceCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ProductId == 0xfaf0 && d.VendorId == 0x0403);

            //Open the device
            if (selectedDevice != null)
            {
                selectedDevice.Open();

                //Get the first config number of the interface
                selectedDevice.ClaimInterface(selectedDevice.Configs[0].Interfaces[0].Number);

                //Open up the endpoints
                var writeEndpoint = selectedDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep02);
                var readEnpoint = selectedDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep03);

                //Create a buffer with some data in it
                var dataToSend = new byte[6];
                dataToSend[0] = 43;
                dataToSend[1] = 04;
                dataToSend[2] = 01;
                dataToSend[3] = 00;
                dataToSend[4] = 22;
                dataToSend[5] = 01;

                //Write six bytes
                writeEndpoint.Write(dataToSend, 3000, out var bytesWritten);
                
                Console.WriteLine("Number of bytes written: " + bytesWritten);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This correctly identified the three KDC101 brushless motor controllers and returned the line "Number of bytes written: 6" but the motor did not initiate a homing move so I'm guessing the message still isn't getting through.

Comment: What are `WriteEndpointID.Ep01` and `ReadEndpointID.Ep01`? Also, can you verify with the debugger that the correct device is found when you instantiate the `finder`?

Comment: Add the D2XX driver from Add Reference
The endpoint ID Ep01 might not be correct.
Also, see this which may help https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet/issues/73

Comment: Also, have you tried exploring the [C# Examples from FTDI](https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/code-examples/csharp-examples/)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with _JetBrains Rider_, but I'll focus on the fact that you mentioned _serial port_ at least a couple of times. When communicating with a serial port device, one needs to ensure that one is using the correct cable - it seems that you've already verfied this. Next, one needs to read all the documentation for the [Serial Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) class.

Comment: Then one needs to refer to the documentation for the hardware device and ensure that one sets the appropriate property values for the instance of _Serial Port_ so that they match the settings on the hardware device. Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac, but if you have access to Windows, the following post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425. There are some PowerShell commands at the end of the post that may be helpful in determining the appropriate property values when using the _SerialPort_ class.

Comment: There is no such thing as _NET core 4.8.1_ - it's .NET Framework. See [Microsoft .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) and [Microsoft .NET and .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core)

Comment: You don't use LibUsbDotNet to talk to FTDI chips.  You use the serial port interface (COM*n* on Windows, /dev/ttyUSB*n* on *nix) if it's enabled, and the D2XX library if the serial port emulation is disabled.

Comment: The `-lftd2xx` is for C++ programs.  C# can't do static linking, but p/invoke (triggered by `DllImport` attributes on function declarations) provides access to shared libraries.

Comment: Since your new to C#, you may consider starting with the VCP (virtual COM port) driver - the usage should be simpler.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input! @JPAlioto I believe WriteEndpointID.Ep01 and ReadEndpointID.Ep01 are methods in LibUsbDotNet. I got them from following [this example](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet/blob/master/src/Examples/Read.Write/ReadWrite.cs#L29).

Comment: @I_Al-thamary Adding a reference to the D2XX driver /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.1.4.16.dylib doesn't seem to be supported (the file is greyed out and I can't click it). I had partial success using Ep.2 (see the edit at the end of my original question).

Comment: @NPras thank you for pointing me to those examples. The [webpage](https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/code-examples/csharp-examples/) you linked to seems to imply that the D2XX drivers and FTD2XX.DLL are separate things? If I've understood correctly, the DLL is used in the code to call methods from the D2XX driver? The managed .net wrapper (FTD2XX_NET.DLL) that is listed on the FTDI webpage is specifically for Windows, which doesn't fit my platform-independent objective. I tried referencing the FTD2XX_NET.DLL in JetBrains Rider anyway, but this gave a 'libkernel32.dll' (no such file) error.

Comment: The managed FTDI wrapper is both for Windows and .NET Framework 2.0; it is not going to be any use to you or pretty much anyone. You need to install the VCP driver, which will allow you to address your "USB" devices as the serial devices communicating over USB that they actually are, and then you will be able to write whatever raw data to them you need... basically, do the stuff that @user246821 has told you to. I hope you are ready for a lot of pain and the distinct possibility you won't be able to make this work, because FTDI's hardware and software are both complete and utter rubbish.

Comment: Also, I will say that given the fact that you seem to be quite new to C#, you should seriously consider finding someone more experienced to assist you. Working with FTDI devices and drivers was rough for me as a senior developer with over half a decade's experience; it is liable to be well nigh impossible for you, unless you have both a high pain tolerance for FTDI bugs and the ability to learn very quickly.