C# WinForms application is receiving random data, like '??????', over a SerialPort
In my C# WinForms application, I am using the SerialPort class to read data from a Zebra    DS9308 scanner, which is connected to the PC through an RS232 and Cadyce converter. When I  checked these scanners with the Docklight utility software to see the actual data being received through the COM port, everything worked fine for three individual scanners. However, when I started my WinForms application and opened three serial ports, it received random data like "????" over the SerialPort for each scanner, and triggered the serialPort_DataReceived method.
I thought that maybe opening three serial ports at the same time causes the random data issue, but the same logic is working fine on another PC. I have changed the RS232 cable and Cadyce converter, but the same issue is arising. Is there any issue related to the CPU, RS232 cable, or Cadyce converter?
Here is my code:
`private SerialPort serialPort;
private SerialPort serialPort2;
private SerialPort serialPort3;

private void FinalForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
comPortRead();

serialPort.Open();
serialPort2.Open();
serialPort3.Open();

serialPort.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
serialPort2.DataReceived += serialPort2_DataReceived;
serialPort3.DataReceived += serialPort3_DataReceived;

GetPlanWorkOrder();
}

private void comPortRead()
{
try
{
string[] array = File.ReadAllLines("com_ports.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
serialPort = new SerialPort(array[0], 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort2 = new SerialPort(array[1], 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
serialPort3 = new SerialPort(array[2], 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
MessageBox.Show("COM port file not found");
}
catch (IOException ex2)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex2.ToString());
}
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
try
{
string text = serialPort.ReadLine()?.Trim();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
string logPath = "C:\\TTPL PETROL TANK\\serialPortLog.txt";

// Ensure the log file exists
if (!File.Exists(logPath))
{
File.Create(logPath).Dispose();
}

// Log the received data for debugging
File.AppendAllText(logPath, $"{DateTime.Now}: {text}{Environment.NewLine}");
}

// Use Invoke to update richTextBox1 from the UI thread
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
richTextBox1.AppendText($"DATA RECEIVED ON SCANNER 1: {text}{Environment.NewLine}");
});
if (button3.Text == "SET PLAN")
{
richTextBox1.Text = "PLEASE SET PLAN";
}
else
{
if (openScanner1)
{
//string text = serialPort.ReadLine()?.Trim();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Length > 9)
{
if (CheckPartNoAndWorkOrderExist(text, _WorkOrder, _LotNo) ||Station1.Contains(text))
{
UpdateRichTextBox("THIS PART IS ALREADY SCANNED...!!!", Color.Red);
}
else
{
string subString = text.Substring(0, 8);
if (subString == _TankNo)
{
//station1Tank = text;
TankData.Enqueue(text);
}
Station1.Add(text);

//Station1Part.Add(text);

ScannedPartsData.Enqueue(text);

Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
if (!coilValue1)
{
UpdateRichTextBox("PLEASE PLACE BOX AT SENSOR", Color.Red);
}
else
{
richTextBox1.Text = "";
Thread.Sleep(200);
CompareReceivedData(subString);
}
});
}
}
text = "";
}
}
serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
richTextBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString());
});
}
}`


Most probably that only means the data has no character representation in whatever encoding is used in the display component.

What do i do now filder?

If the same software works for the same type of hardware on another system, then try and find out what the difference is. System settings (language, ..) and maybe also config of the zebra.

I have scanned restore default, RS232, Disable Continues reading barcodes from zebra scanner manual, still it is same.

Is there any chances of electrical interfernce to serialPort.
because when i run application serialPort1, serialPort2, serialPort3 are getting triggered automatically even while no parts barcode or QR code scanned.

Are you sure 9800 Baud, 8N1 is the correct port setting?

Might not be connected to what you see but using Readline in the DataReceived Event is wrong. Do either or. Either use ReadExisting in the DataReceived event and then fill a buffer until you have a complete line/barcode or just do loop with ReadLine without the DataReceived event.

According to DS9308 Hands-Free Imager Support: Confirm that you have the following equipment...Zebra proprietary USB cable Emulating a COM/Serial Port over USB Using CDC Driver has a barcode to scan, as well as some information. The barcode is also on page 240 of DS9308 doc

You'll need to read all of the documentation for SerialPort class. Then refer to the documentation for the Zebra DS9308,  On page 88, scan Add Enter Key barcode, so your data will end with CRLF. Also see SerialPort.NewLine. To configure baud rate, see page 267.

According to page 271 of the documentation, the default value appears to be Enable ACK/NAK Handshaking: After transmitting data, the scanner expects either an ACK or NAK
response from the host. The scanner also ACKs or NAKs messages from the host.. You may want to change this - at least during initial testing.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957066/serial-to-usb-cable-from-a-scale-to-pc-some-values-are-just-question-marks/65971845#65971845

Thank You everyone for your contribution, problem is solved.
