Use and Connect to EPP (Pin pad) in my .Net program
I want to use SZZT EPP XFS and write a program to get PIN from Pin pad in .Net Framework
This is done in the test program of the device itself, but in the program I wrote, it does not connect
This is my Code:
static SerialPort port;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
        port.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Connection established. Sending command...");
        byte[] command = new byte[] { 0x02, 0x47, 0x03 };
        port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int bytesToRead = port.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];
        port.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

        Console.WriteLine("Received Data: " + BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error while reading data: {ex.Message}");
    }
}


Why have you chosen to use a Console app for this?

The following may be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425

You may consider reading all of the documentation for SerialPort. If the properties aren't properly set to match those of your serial port device, then you won't be able to communicate with the device.

You may wish to re-evaluate your placement of Console.ReadKey();.
